# Difference between request_irq and __interrupt

Tags: c, linux, kernel, interrupt, irq

From what I read both are used to register interrupt handlers. I saw lots of `request_irq` calls in kernel code but not even one `__interrupt` call. Is `__interrupt` some way to register a handler from user space?

Answer (score 8):

`request_irq` is essentially a wrapper call to `request_threaded_irq`, which allocates the IRQ resources and enables the IRQ.  That's paraphrased from the comment block in `kernel/irq/manage.c`, [Line #1239](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L1239).

Basically, you want to use `request_irq` if you need to setup interrupt handling for a device of some kind.  Make sure that whatever subsystem you are working in doesn't already provide a wrapper for `request_irq`, too.  I.e., if you are working on a device driver, consider using the `devm_*` family of calls to auto-manage the minutiae, like freeing unused variables and such.  See `devm_request_threaded_irq` at [Line #29](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/devres.c#L29) in `kernel/irq/devres.c` for a better explanation.  Its equivalent call (and the one you would most likely use) is `devm_request_irq`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember __interrupt() is used to declare a function as ISR in userspace. I am not sure where I have this from but I'll come back to you as soon as I found the spot.